# Assigning service principal to azure MSI cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to deploy an app to an Azure cluster from a .gitlab-ci.yml. My cluster is currently using managed identities so I can't do that. I tried to add a new service principal in order to use credentials from the CI using:

```
az aks update-credentials \                    
--resource-group <> \
--name <> \
--reset-service-principal \
--service-principal <> \
--client-secret <>
```

However, I get the following error:

> (BadRequest) Updating service principal profile is not allowed on MSI cluster.
> Code: BadRequest
> Message: Updating service principal profile is not allowed on MSI cluster.

What should I do?

Comment: you should be able to deploy with MSI enable. What the issue you are getting ? you probably need to enable RBAC so you can deploy to your cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are currently using managed identities make sure to assign role and scopes to this service principal.

I agree with ***Thomas*** check whether you have Enabled RBAC deploy to your cluster.

To assign role and scopes to the service principal please try the below command mentioned in this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create-for-rbac)

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac [--cert]
                         [--create-cert]
                         [--display-name]
                         [--keyvault]
                         [--role]
                         [--scopes]
                         [--sdk-auth {false, true}]
                         [--skip-assignment{false,true}]
                         [--years]
```

You can also make use of **`az role assignment create`** to create role assignments

Make sure for `--client-secret` using azure bash terminal use **`${SP_SECRET@Q}`.**

To know more in detail please ***refer*** below link:

[Update service principal key authorization for Azure Kubernetes Service (opsmx.com)](https://www.opsmx.com/blog/create-and-update-the-service-principal-key-for-azure-kubernetes-service-aks/) by Yugandhar Kumar Pidugu